# Пытался подключить к боту базу данных sqlite базу создал а как подключить что бы все сохранялось не знаю

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, telegram-bot, sqlite3

Вот код (это эхо бот) там снизу функция lalala отправляет сообщение как сделать что бы она подключилась к базе и сохраняла туда сообщения

```
import telebot
import config
import sqlite3

bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.TOKEN)

__connection = None


def get_connection():
    global __connection
    if __connection is None:
        __connection = sqlite3.connect('anketa.db')
    return __connection


def init_db(force: bool = False):
    conn = get_connection()

    c = conn.cursor()


    if force:
        c.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS user_message')

    c.execute('''
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user_message (
            id          INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,    
            user_id     INTEGER NOT NULL,
            text        TEXT NOT NULL
        )
    ''')
    conn.commit()


def add_message(user_id: int, text: str):
    conn = get_connection()
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute('INSERT INTO user_message (user_id, text) VALUES (?, ?)', (user_id, text))
    conn.commit()

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])


def lalala(message):

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, message.text)
    add_message((message.from_user.first_name, message.from_user.last_name, str(message.from_user.id), message.text))

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: `add_message(message.from_user.id, message.text)`

Answer (score 0):

Создание базы данных

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect("mydatabase.db") # или :memory: чтобы сохранить в RAM
cursor = conn.cursor()

# Создание таблицы
cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE albums
                  (title text, artist text, release_date text,
                   publisher text, media_type text)
               """)

# Вставляем данные в таблицу
cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO albums
                  VALUES ('Glow', 'Andy Hunter', '7/24/2012',
                  'Xplore Records', 'MP3')"""
               )

# Сохраняем изменения
conn.commit()

# Вставляем множество данных в таблицу используя безопасный метод "?"
albums = [('Exodus', 'Andy Hunter', '7/9/2002', 'Sparrow Records', 'CD'),
          ('Until We Have Faces', 'Red', '2/1/2011', 'Essential Records', 'CD'),
          ('The End is Where We Begin', 'Thousand Foot Krutch', '4/17/2012', 'TFKmusic', 'CD'),
          ('The Good Life', 'Trip Lee', '4/10/2012', 'Reach Records', 'CD')]

cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO albums VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)", albums)
conn.commit()
```

Редактирование/удаление

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect("mydatabase.db")
cursor = conn.cursor()

sql = """
UPDATE albums 
SET artist = 'John Doe' 
WHERE artist = 'Andy Hunter'
"""

cursor.execute(sql)
conn.commit()
```

Основные запросы :

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect("mydatabase.db")
#conn.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
cursor = conn.cursor()

sql = "SELECT * FROM albums WHERE artist=?"
cursor.execute(sql, [("Red")])
print(cursor.fetchall()) # or use fetchone()

print("Here's a listing of all the records in the table:")
for row in cursor.execute("SELECT rowid, * FROM albums ORDER BY artist"):
    print(row)

print("Results from a LIKE query:")
sql = "SELECT * FROM albums WHERE title LIKE 'The%'"
cursor.execute(sql)

print(cursor.fetchall())
```

Источник https://python-scripts.com/sqlite

Comment: Я то базу сам сделал я не знаю как в этой библиотеке подключить самого бота к базе данных